# How to add an element from a looping list to a name of each function?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I am taking machine learning classes and have some questions about the for loop.
for example, I have a list category =["cat","dog","car"]
I want to loop through this category and create a model with name including the element(i.e. model_cat, model_dog, model_car)

for i in category:
     model = graphlab.nearest_neighbors.create(xxxxxxx)

in this case, each model has the same name "model". Is there a way to add unique labels to the model? Thanks.

Comment: Yes put them in a list an access by index or use a dict to access by name

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly meant by model but looks like you just need another list. Try this.

```
category = ["Cat","Dog","Car"]
model = []

for i in category:
    if i not in model:
        model.append('Model_' + i)

print(model)
```

Output:

```
['Model_Cat', 'Model_Dog', 'Model_Car']
```